# OS (Fedora) not booting after disconnect/reconnect hard drive

Tags: bios, fedora, uefi

I have two hard drive install on a system, one with Fedora installed, and one with Windows. They are NOT dual booting and they do not power on at the same time.

I disconnected from the Fedora hard drive and connected to the Windows hard drive to do some work, but after I connected back to the Fedora hard drive, the system won't boot. It says no system install and insert boot disk.

I know the Fedora OS is still there because when I connected the hard drive to another computer I can still see all the files.

One assumption I came up with is that the system BIOS is UEFI BIOS and Fedora is installed using LVM, and there might be a conflict there, but I am not sure.

Any help on the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

UEFI has nothing to do with the filesystem in question.  There are a few options.  The MBR went toes up.  The drive went kaput (it's a technical term), or perhaps the drive did not get connected back up all the way.  Does the BIOS see it?  Does this system see it when booted to a live CD?

Comment: The hard drive is definitely connected, not sure how to see it with live CD. But BIOS definitely sees it.

Comment: Get a liveCD like the Fedora install CD, SystemRescueCD, Debian, Ubuntu...  anything like that.  What do you get when you do `fdisk -l`?